# Concurrent threads waiting for tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I've googled this a lot now and came to no answers - hence why I'm asking.

Been a day now, but I can't get round some threading concepts which is probably why my code is a mess.

I'm spawning 3 threads. Fine.

When thread 2 spawns, thread 1 "stops" which I assume means it dies. Same for thread 2 and 3.

I'm putting these threads within an active pool.

What I'm struggling with is, keeping all 3 threads running at the same time and waiting. I'd like to have a method which on random time intervals assigns a thread to a task.

From what I've gathered, the reason my threads are dieing is because my worker class is returning. However, having played with it and put it around a loop (while 1), I still can't get anything working.

Any ideas?

```
import logging
import random
import threading
import time

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG, format = '(%(threadName)-2s) %(message)s')

class ActivePool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ActivePool, self).__init__()

        self.active = []
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def activate(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.append(name)
            logging.debug('Running wheel: %s', self.active)
            self.move(name)

    def move(self, name):
        while name.is_alive():
            logging.debug('yes')

    def inactive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.remove(name)
            logging.debug('Running wheel: %s', self.active)

    def rtime(self):
        self.rt = random.randint(5, 10)
        t = threading.Timer(rt, self.revent)

    def join(self):
        for t in self.active:
            t.join()

    def check(self):
        for t in self.active:
            if t.is_alive():
                print t

def worker(s, pool):
    logging.debug('Wheel inactive')

    with s:
        #name = threading.currentThread().getName()
        thread = threading.currentThread()
        logging.debug('ACTIVATING')
        pool.activate(thread)
        #time.sleep(2)
        #pool.inactive(thread)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = ActivePool()
    s = threading.Semaphore()

    for i in range(0, 6):
        t = threading.Thread(target = worker, name = str(i + 1), args = (s, pool))
        pool.activate(t)
        t.start()

    logging.debug('here')
```

Comment: Even adding some pseudocode here would help. Gonna be pretty tough to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: @phyllisdiller added

Comment: When I clean things up a bit, I get thread 1 spinning up and not dying. 
But I'm not sure of the intent. You want to essentially have a pool of threads waiting to be assigned tasks, correct?

However, your main function, as well as your worker function (the thing the thread is going to run), activates the thread. You shouldn't be activating the thread from within the thread.

Comment: Try using a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

Comment: @phyllisdiller that is correct yes. So where would I activate the thread? And is there a need to join?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I've rejiggered things a bit. Essentially what you want is this order of command:

- Construct an ActivePool.
- Add threads to your ActivePool.
- Call ActivePool.start() to begin the thread.
- The worker threads run the worker function, with shared data protected by the semaphore.
- The main thread awaits the completion of all threads.

You do not need to join the threads.

If you do add a random task, you'd add it to some list (which you'd have to lock on with your semaphore) which the worker function will pull from and perform work on. If the worker sees something in the list, it will pull it off the list and perform the relevant action. If there's nothing to do, have the thread sleep.

You may want to add all your threads to your thread pool before you spin them up (i.e., make a list inside ActivePool, then do pool.activate() and have that activate each thread in turn).

```
import logging
import random
import threading
import time

logger = logging.getLogger("thread_logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class ActivePool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ActivePool, self).__init__()

        self.active = []
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def activate(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.append(name)
            logger.debug('Running wheel: %s', self.active)
            t.start()

    def inactive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.remove(name)
            logger.debug('Running wheel: %s', self.active)

    def rtime(self):
        self.rt = random.randint(5, 10)
        t = threading.Timer(rt, self.revent)

    def join(self):
        for t in self.active:
            t.join()

    def check(self):
        for t in self.active:
            if t.is_alive():
                return True

def worker(s, pool):

    logger.debug('Worker spinning up')

    for x in range(0, 3):
        with s:
            logger.debug('Thread ID: ' + str(threading.currentThread().ident) + ' DO WORK: ' + str(x))
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pool = ActivePool()
    s = threading.Semaphore()

    for i in range(0, 2):
        t = threading.Thread(target = worker, name = str(i + 1), args = (s, pool))
        pool.activate(t)

    while(pool.check()):
        print("Worker thread still workin yo.")
        time.sleep(2)
    logger.debug('Finito.')
```